# Sign Apk for Cordova App developed in Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I have created cordova App using Visual Studio 2015.
If I build App in Release mode unsigned APK created.
Now I want to deploy the App.
How can I create keystore? 
How can I sign my apk created in Released folder?

Note: I dont have android studio

Answer (score 3):

I followed MS instructions from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx), see section Package and Sign Android app (shown below), and it worked for me.

To sign an Android app for distribution

1.Generate a keystore and provide the information required to create a certificate (private key). For more information, see Signing your applications in the Android documentation.

2.When you have created a keystore, open the res\native\android folder.

3.Open the ant.properties file, and enter information about the keystore and the alias.
The Key.store property in ant.properties must specify a relative or absolute path to the certificate file.

4.Put the keystore you created either in the same folder as ant.properties, or in some other location. (For example, for security reasons, you might not want to check the keystore into source control.)

5.Build the Android app.

When you build the app, Visual Studio will sign the package with the credentials you supplied.

Comment: this doesn't work, still the release apk file is not generated using these steps.

Comment: @Mostafa - this question is about signing the Ark file. If your ark file is not generated see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125316/build-doesn-t-produce-apk/29128203#29128203
The instructions for signing are directly from MS, and they work!