# Build doesn’t produce apk

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I’m using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1 on VS 2013. Building a simple Blank App template for Android. Build succeeds with no errors, but I can’t find compiled APK file anywhere! bin\Android\ folder contains empty Release and Debug folders.  Below is my output from VS build. I don’t see the actual call to Cordova to do the Android build, should it be there? Ripple emulator works just fine.

Thank you.

Build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Release Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.0 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\DUZVVBQ3.2O1\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create apk, you need to select target as Device or Emulator. Apk is not created for Ripple because no package deployment is required, it is just launching the index.html in browser.

Comment: New issue - build exits with the following error  - "Error 152 ....\bld\Distribution\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1" 
Running build.bat manually after that works, I get CordovaApp-debug.apk package build

Comment: Solved my last compile problem by adding space to the project directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029116/visual-studio-cordova-build-fails